# rake aborted! undefined method `mtime' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, joosy

I am hitting a

```
rake aborted! 
undefined method `mtime' for nil:NilClass
```

error when trying to precompile a Rails / Joosy / Foundation 4 app with Phusion Passenger.

The command I am using is

```
  bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

I have tried grep -r "mtime" which took forever and didn't seem to return anything (although I didn't let it finish) and a search of my local files for the same term returned nothing.

```
ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-linux]
Rails 3.2.13
Phusion Passenger version 4.0.2
```

The full trace is as follows. Anything else that might be useful please let me know.

Thanks.

```
$ bundle exec rake assets:precompile
/home/entracked/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby /home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby- 1.9.3-p392@global/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
rake aborted!
undefined method `mtime' for nil:NilClass
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@hub_blog/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:128:in `block in build_dependency_paths'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@hub_blog/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:127:in `build_dependency_paths'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@hub_blog/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:17:in `initialize'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@hub_blog/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:249:in `new'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@hub_blog/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:249:in `block in build_asset'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@hub_blog/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:270:in `circular_call_protection'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@hub_blog/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:248:in `build_asset'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@hub_blog/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `block in build_asset'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@hub_blog/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in `cache_asset'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@hub_blog/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:92:in `build_asset'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@hub_blog/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:169:in `find_asset'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@hub_blog/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:60:in `find_asset'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@hub_blog/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@hub_blog/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:252:in `new'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@hub_blog/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:252:in `build_asset'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@hub_blog/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `block in build_asset'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@hub_blog/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in `cache_asset'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@hub_blog/gems/sprockets-2  .2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:92:in `build_asset'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@hub_blog/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:169:in `find_asset'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@hub_blog/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:60:in `find_asset'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@hub_blog/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:19:in `block in compile'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@hub_blog/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:219:in `block in each_logical_path'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@hub_blog/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:206:in `block (2 levels) in each_file'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@hub_blog/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:196:in `each'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@hub_blog/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:196:in `each_entry'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@hub_blog/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:204:in `block in each_file'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@hub_blog/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:203:in `each'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@hub_blog/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:203:in `each_file'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@hub_blog/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:217:in `each_logical_path'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@hub_blog/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:18:in `compile'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@hub_blog/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:56:in `internal_precompile'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@hub_blog/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:70:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@hub_blog/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Command failed with status (1): [/home/entracked/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p39...]
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:53:in `block in create_shell_runner'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in `sh'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:80:in `ruby'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in `ruby'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@hub_blog/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:12:in `ruby_rake_task'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@hub_blog/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:21:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@hub_blog/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
 /home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@hub_blog/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/entracked/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@hub_blog/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

EDIT

So further reading makes me thing it is related to https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/issues/141 which basically says the error message are not very useful, but that is probably related to the require_tree manifest in application.js.

I'm not very sure what is going on but I wonder if there is something missing from mine

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require foundation
//= require_tree .

$(document).foundation();
```

also tried adding this line

```
//= require_tree ./blog
```

because I have a joosy.ws (front end js framework) application created in assets/javascripts/blog. Not sure if this will be included by default. Neither option seems to fix the issue.

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2328

Comment: Thanks @Sparda I think that is related to this https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/issues/141 as well. I'm not exactly sure I understand exactly how the require_tree works? - please see my edit above.

Comment: `require_tree` tells Rails to precompile all the files in the current tree. Sorry but I won't be of much help...

Comment: Did you try commenting that out line by line? Which line causes the error?

Comment: Also which version of Joosy do you use?

Comment: @inossidabile I'm not actually sure how I got over it, rvm and ruby are completely new to me, I think I just hammered away at the terminal apt-getting like it was going out of fashion. I don't normally like leaving open questions on here, but truely I tried so many combinations of things that I didn't understand that night, I don't have much clue as to how I got it fixed

Comment: @inossidabile as a side note, do you have a schedule for releasing the Authentication part of the Joosy guide? I really enjoyed the framework, but it was a conceptual hurdle beyond me, so for the time being I have gone back to basics in trying to understand it from a rails perspective.

Comment: Right now we are working on the 1.2 branch. Documentation will be forced after the release which will take at least one more month (or so). But feel free to ask here, I'll try to help.